# Return time formatted based on a custom selection

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

In Google Sheets, I have 3 columns.

1. Column A contains one of two text strings: `12-Hour` or `24-Hour`.
2. Column B contains a time that may be in a 12-hour or 24-hour format. eg. `2:00 PM` , `14:00` , etc.
3. In Column C I would like a formula that will return the time from column B with the format based on the selection in column A.

### Sample Data

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Selection** | **Time** | **Result** |
| **2** | 12-Hour | 2:00 PM | 2:00 PM |
| **3** | 24-Hour | 2:00 PM | 14:00 |
| **4** | 12-Hour | 14:00 | 2:00 PM |
| **5** | 24-Hour | 14:00 | 14:00 |

What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()`, like this:

`=text(B2, if(A2 = "12-Hour", "h:mm am/pm", "h:mm"))`

See [text()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139).